# How to change width of div?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

Okay, I'm making a greasemonkey script and I'm trying to shrink the right column in facebook that has the ads on down to 1px so i can stretch the relevant content in the middle, but everything I try doesn't work!
I tried this and I didn't work:

```
document.getElementById('rightCol').style.width = '1px';
```

This is the CSS that tells the sidebar to be 244px's

```
#rightCol{margin-top:-10000px;float:right;padding-right:0;width:244px;word-wrap:break-word}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? The script you provided works fine for me. Try it in console to check, maybe there's something wrong with the Greasemonkey?

Comment: Your right! I might just have something messed up in greasemonkey. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I got it working now! :)

Comment: http://goo.gl/nYhQN thats the script if anyone cares.

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
window.addEventListener ("load", function() {
    document.getElementById('rightCol').style.display = 'none';
}, false);
```

worked for me.

Comment: I needed to actually shrink the rightCol down to 1px or 0px so that I could stretch the relevant feed, so this ended up working: `document.getElementById('rightCol').style.width = '0px';`and then I used `document.getElementById('whateveriwant').style.visibility = 'hidden';` to Hide whatever I needed hidden

Answer (score 2):

You can try to hide the whole column:

```
document.getElementById('rightCol').style.display = "none"
```

Comment: Whats the difference between that and this: document.getElementById('rightCol').style.visibility = 'hidden'; I'm just curious?

Comment: display: none will remove the element from the flow and because of that hide it
visibility: hidden will not take the element from the flow but just hide it. (the space is still used but empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try jquery. Well I don't find any mistake in your code.
But try this.

```
$('#rightCol').attr('style','width: 10px;');
```

Or you may apply class on that particular column and select it by class selector like:

`$('.rightColClass').attr('style','width: 10px;');` // It will apply width on all the element contains this class.

Comment: hmm... I'm using greasemonkey, so I dont know if that will work.

Comment: Three ways to set the width via jQuery and you used the worst one... The best one is `.width(10)`; the not-so-bad is `.css('width', '10px')` - but `.attr()`? Nope.